# How do I permanently configure the DNS resolution in Ubuntu for ALL programs/layers for specific interfaces

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, nsswitch, resolvconf

Is there a way I can permanently set the DNS preference of my Ubuntu laptop for specific network interfaces?

I am relying on a wifi network that is not that predictable.
I don't have access to the edit-mode of the wifi router management console, and every now and then the wifi connection drops off and then comes back again.

This means I have to constantly invoke this command to "refresh" my DNS entries: `sudo resolvectl dns 3 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8`.

The problem originally generated from web browser `DNS_*` errors (many different e.g. `DNS_PROBE_STARTED`, `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`, `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG`, `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET` etc) I was seeing, so I figured out this wifi network (router)
is using dedicated DNS entries from the ISP (Internet Service Provider).
I can see these details (custom IP addresses) on the router config dashboard but I cannot change those settings.

Also: I can see that my Ubuntu DNS relies on the default gateway of the wifi network (the router).
I found this out with these commands where the IP addresses match:

```bash
# check my local Ubuntu DNS details for all interfaces
resolvectl dns
# find out the default gateway (it should be the router IP address)
ip route
```

I think this means that my laptop is dynamically relying on the gateway (router) for DNS resolution and that the router is configured to use some obscure IP addresses from the ISP (Internet Service Provider). Is this correct?

I changed the Global DNS by modifying this file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`
by appending this:

```
DNS=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4
```

Then I did this:

```bash
# make sure to restart the DNS daemon
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
# check what DNS is being used by each interface
resolvectl status
```

But of course this is being overridden by my wifi interface on which I don't know how to act, what to configure to make it work with my preferred DNS entries.

For the sake of completeness I also did this to make sure the web browser was relying on a fresh DNS cache without throwing `DNS_*` errors (I am not sure this is correct/needed, is it?):

```bash
# check current DNS cache
resolvectl statistics
# flush DNS cache
resolvectl flush-caches
```

If I check the bottom of the file `/etc/resolv.conf` then I see this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan
```

I think this DNS trouble might be related to that entry `nameserver 127.0.0.53`
but I also know that this file `/etc/resolv.conf` is generated automatically (and perhaps refreshed automatically) by `systemd-resolved.service` where `127.0.0.53` means that the laptop relies on this local IP address for DNS which is managed by `systemd-resolved`
so I think I shouldn't be manually changing it.

I have this feeling that different programs/commands use different places/layers to figure out the DNS configuration.
Like if somehow I change the `resolvectl` / `systemd-resolved.service` settings, then maybe the browser may be reading the DNS config from somewhere else like that `/etc/resolv.conf` file or things like `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? Is this the case?

I would like to:

- make this command `sudo resolvectl dns 3 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8` PERMANENT (across reboot and across wifi disconnect/connect cycles)
- change all the other config files e.g. `/etc/resolv.conf` or `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and similar

to rely on my preferred DNS configuration details. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't indicated if this is a Desktop or Server installation. Either way, I'll try to explain.

First, let's look at the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan
```

This is showing `127.0.0.53` as the nameserver, which is expected and is the local caching stub resolver. In fact, if you type the command `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`, you'll notice that it's a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`(or at least it should be), which is where the local nameserver is defined.

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Dec 31  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

The stub resolver caches DNS queries so that future queries are faster and don't have to query any uplink nameservers. Let's see this in action.

Open up two terminal windows. In one terminal, which we'll call Terminal #1, run a `tcpdump` with the following command. Substitute `wlp9s0` with your interface that DNS queries are expected to go out. If it's the only interface connected to the internet, then use that.

```
sudo tcpdump -ni wlp9s0 -p port 53
```

Then on the other window, Terminal #2, run the following command:

```
dig google.com
```

The output in Terminal #2 will be the following and indicates `127.0.0.53` as the nameserver:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54920
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     294 IN  A   142.251.46.206

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 12 19:47:07 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

In Terminal #1 with `tcpdump` running, there will either be no output or some activity. If you've visited this site before, then the query should be in your local cache and won't show any output from `tcpdump`. If not, then you should see output with a query to your uplink server. I'll assume you've previously queried google.com as I proceed, which means there's no output just yet.

Next, let's clear the local DNS cache. In Terminal #2, enter the following:

```
sudo resolvectl flush-caches
```

And then run `dig google.com` again in Terminal #2. This time around, you should see output via `tcpdump` in Terminal #1 querying an uplink server you've defined or received via DHCP. In the following output, I see the server `208.65.212.34` being queried, which is one of my DNS servers given to me via DHCP on my wifi link.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni wlp9s0 -p port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp9s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:50:55.534164 IP 172.23.123.82.39024 > 208.65.212.34.53: 36626+ [1au] A? google.com. (39)
19:50:55.550242 IP 208.65.212.34.53 > 172.23.123.82.39024: 36626 1/0/1 A 142.251.46.206 (55)
```

In both queries we've done, the output of `dig google.com` showed `127.0.0.53` as the nameserver being queried, and this will always be the case. But behind the scenes, the uplink server is queried if it hasn't been queried before and stored in cache.

So let's now setup DNS servers on a specific interface in both a Desktop environment and a server.

---

**Defining DNS servers per interface - DESKTOP**

Within the desktop environment, it's very easy to assign DNS servers on each interface. With a wifi interface, it's most likely setup with DHCP. So open  wifi settings, click the IPv4 page, and simply add a DNS server similar to the following image where I define `8.8.8.8` as an additional DNS server:

[image]

If you don't want to use any DNS servers delivered to you from the DHCP server, simply uncheck *Automatic*.

In the terminal, run `resolvectl status` and you'll see that this additional DNS server has been added to that interface. If it's not there yet, you may have to toggle your wifi adapter on/off or reboot.

```
Link 3 (wlp9s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 208.65.212.34
         DNS Servers: 208.65.212.34
                      208.65.212.2 
                      8.8.8.8      
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Just repeat as necessary for other interfaces.

---

**Defining DNS servers per interface - SERVER**

In the server environment, you can define nameservers per interface within the Netplan configuration file. The following example is from a Virtual Machine I created with two interfaces. The first interface, `eth0`, gets it's IP address via DHCP, but I'm overriding the DNS servers given to me, effectively ignoring them, and then defining my own. The second interface, `eth1`, is set with a static IP address and manually defined DNS Servers.

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: true
    dhcp4-overrides:
      use-dns: false
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 9.9.9.9
  eth1:
    dhcp4: false
    addresses: [192.168.5.11/24]
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
```

After any changes, run `sudo netplan try` to apply the changes. Then run `resolvectl status`, and you'll see that each interface has their own DNS servers. If not, you may need to reboot the system before the changes actually take effect, which is what I've experienced when making changes.

```
$ resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9

Link 3 (eth1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This kind of configuration is reaching the limit of what Netplan can do, however. To have complete control over the interface DNS settings, specifically regarding the DNS Default Route, then the interfaces need to be configured with *networkd* directly and not Netplan. See the man page for [systemd.network(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.network.5.html).

---

In the end, what we're talking about here is basically split DNS, where you can configure specific domains to query specific servers. This helps with regards to VPNs, DNS Default Routes, search domains, etc. To read up more on the subject, check out the following links:

- [systemd-resolved: introduction to split DNS](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-resolved-introduction-to-split-dns/)
- [Understanding systemd-resolved, Split DNS, and VPN Configuration](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2020/12/17/understanding-systemd-resolved-split-dns-and-vpn-configuration/)
- [systemd-resolved.service and VPNs](https://systemd.io/RESOLVED-VPNS/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this context! Gold! I am on a laptop with Xubuntu desktop. I found out I could create a file in `/etc/systemd/network/${MY_NET_INTERFACE_NAME}.network` containing something like `[Match] Name=${MY_NET_INTERFACE_NAME} [Network] DHCP=yes DNS=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4` then do `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` to persist the changes. Did you encounter anything like this? Reason for asking is that I would like to avoid GUI approach in favor of config scripts and would like to avoid more tools e.g. `netplan` and stick with minimal SystemD NetworkD and ResolveD

Comment: @TPPZ That is certainly another way to configure the interfaces. In fact, I tend to prefer that over Netplan and the syntax in the YAML files.